# has to do with vs has something to do with

Tags: differences, idioms, redundancy

What's the difference between the meanings of these two sentences?

> My homework **has to do with** last week's activity.
>
> My homework **has something to do with** last week's activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use of "something" here implies **uncertainty** - it suggests that you know that there's a connection but you're not sure what it is.  The other time you would use "something" like this is when you want the person you're speaking to to **guess** what the connection is.  In both cases, the use of "something" begs the question "What is the "something"?"

This is because the word "something" is very vague - it's saying "there is a thing" but it's not telling the listener anything about what it is.

"My homework has to do with last week's activity." still invites people to try to guess the connection, but not as "strongly".